# Are there functions of the metric that are scalars under spatial diffs up to total derivatives?

Tags: general-relativity, coordinate-systems

Let $g_{\mu\nu}$ be a metric on a manifold with a time direction $x^0$ singled out. I'm wondering if there exists a function $F(g_{\mu\nu},\partial_\rho g_{\mu\nu},\ldots)$ that transforms under spatial diffeomorphisms as
\begin{align*}
F(g_{\mu\nu}'(x'),\partial_\rho g_{\mu\nu}'(x'),\ldots)=F(g_{\mu\nu}(x),\partial_\rho g_{\mu\nu}(x),\ldots)+ \nabla_\mu \Lambda^{\mu}(g_{\mu\nu},\partial_\rho g_{\mu\nu},\ldots,x'),
\end{align*}
where $\Lambda$ is some functional of the metric and $x'$. This would imply that the integral
\begin{align*}
\int d^dx\, \sqrt{-g}F
\end{align*}
is invariant under spatial diffs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The Ricci curvature scalar is a contraction of the Ricci tensor which is in turn a contraction of the Riemann tensor.
The Riemann tensor, as a commutator of covariant derivatives, can be expressed using Christoffel symbols and their derivatives. The Christoffel symbols, in turn, can be expressed using the metric and its derivatives.

Therefore, the Ricci scalar is indeed a scalar function of the derivative.

Further more, when considering the ricci scalar, the integral you described is (up to a constant) the Einstein-Hilbert action, and varying it with respect to the metric gives the Einstein (vacuum) field equations.